# Inheritance all Schema from BaseSchma from Mongoo and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `BaseSchema` in Node.js for using the MongoDB.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var util = require("util");

const BaseSchema = new Schema({
  owner: { type: String },
  updateDate: { type: String },
  updateBy: { type: String },
  deleteDate: { type: String },
  deleteby: { type: String },
  createDate: { type: String },
  createBy: { type: String },
});

util.inherits(BaseSchema, Schema);
```

and I need to use that for all `Schema` to set all property of `BaseSchema` for all Schema .

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const uniqueString = require("unique-string");

const GenerSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  generPoster: { type: String, require: true },
  isDelete: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Gener", GenerSchema);
```

**how can I use the `BaseSchame` into all Schema ???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a plugin:

```
module.exports = function BaseSchema(schema, options) {

    schema.add({
      owner: { type: String },
      updateDate: { type: String },
      updateBy: { type: String },
      deleteDate: { type: String },
      deleteby: { type: String },
      createDate: { type: String },
      createBy: { type: String },
    });

}
```

In `Gener.js`, load it

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const uniqueString = require("unique-string");
const BaseSchema = require('./BaseSchema');


const GenerSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  generPoster: { type: String, require: true },
  isDelete: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

GenerSchema.plugin(BaseSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Gener", GenerSchema);
```